# C++ file reading

Tags: c++

I have a file that has a number in which is the number of names that follow. For example:

```
4
bob
jim
bar
ted
```

im trying to write a program to read these names.

```
void process_file(ifstream& in, ofstream& out)
{
    string i,o;
    int tmp1,sp;
    char tmp2;
    prompt_user(i,o);
    in.open (i.c_str());

    if (in.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error opening " << i << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    out.open(o.c_str());
    in >> tmp1;
    sp=tmp1;

    do
    {
        in.get(tmp2);
    } while (tmp2 != '\n');

    in.close();
    out.close();
    cout<< sp;
}
```

So far I am able to read the first line and assign int to sp

I need sp to be a counter for how many names. How do I get this to read the names.
The only problem I have left is how to get the names while ignoring the first number.
Until then i cannot implement my loop.

Comment: replace `while (in >> tmp1)` with just `in >> tmp1`. You tmp1 to have the integer value not anything else.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in loop `while (in >> tmp1) sp=tmp1;` ?

Comment: So, I presume you know how to use `for` to make a loop 'x times'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (in >> tmp1)
        sp=tmp1;
```

This successfuly reads the first `int` from the and then tries to continue. Since the second line is not an `int`, extraction fails, so it stops looping. So far so good.

However, the stream is now in `fail` state, and all subsequent extractions will fail unless you clear the error flags.

Say `in.clear()` right after the first `while` loop.

I don't really see why you wrote a loop to extract a single integer, though. You could just write

```
if (!(in >> sp)) { /* error, no int */ }
```

To read the names, read in `string`s. A loop is fine this time:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::string temp;

while (in >> temp) names.push_back(temp);
```

You'd might want to add a counter somewhere to make sure that the number of names matches the number you've read from the file.

Comment: I edited my program and now it assigns 3 to sp. The problem I have left is getting the names. While ignoring the number

Answer (score 0):

```
int lines;
string line;
inputfile.open("names.txt");
lines << inputfile;
for(i=0; i< lines; ++i){   
   if (std::getline(inputfile, line) != 0){
      cout << line << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assuming that the first loop:

```
while (in >> tmp1)
    sp=tmp1;
```

Is meant to read the number in the beginning, this code should do:

```
in >> tmp1;
```

According to [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) `operator>>`:

> The istream object (*this).
>
> The extracted value or sequence is not returned, but directly stored
>   in the variable passed as argument.

So don't use it in condition, rather use:

```
in >> tmp1;
if( tmp1 < 1){
     exit(5);
}
```

---

Second, **NEVER** rely on assumption that the file is correctly formatted:

```
do {
    in.get(tmp2);
    cout << tmp2 << endl;
} while ( (tmp2 != '\n') && !in.eof());
```

Although whole algorithm seems a bit clumsy to me, this should prevent infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to read a specified number of words from a text file in the way you want.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void process_file() {
    // Get file name.
    std::string fileName;
    std::cin >> fileName;

    // Open file for read access.
    std::ifstream input(fileName);

    // Check if file exists.
    if (!input) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Get number of names.
    int count = 0;
    input >> count;

    // Get names and print to cout.
    std::string token;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        input >> token;
        std::cout << token;
    }
}
```